# Как мне указать данные в теле запроса при добавлении на сервер,чтобы получить правильный код от сервера

Tags: python-3.x, requests

На сервер данные приходят в таком виде
      "id": 1513, 
      "name": "1234567890", 
      "position": "0987654321"
При запуске кода данные не добавляются.В теле запроса нужно только имя и позиция.Получаю код 400, а нужен 201. Что изменить и почему?

```
import requests
import json
data={"name" :"alex" ,"position" :"qwerty" }
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r=requests.post('http://&&&&&&&&&&',headers=headers,data=data)
r.status_code
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: код в вопросе, указанные в тексте данные никак не может отправить. Что сервер точно ожидает получить? Вы вероятно хотели json параметр, а не data использовать (судя по Content-type)

Answer (score 0):

**Попробуйте так**

```
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36\
        (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        }
```

Comment: Описание ошибки 400. Ошибка 400: Bad request — ошибка сервера появившаяся в HTTP/1.1. Эта ошибка, означает ни что иное, как ответ сервера, которому «не понравился» ваш запрос (запрос вашего браузера).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ! Проблему решил переписав код.

```
    import json
    import requests
    url = 'http://q.com/candidates'        
    parameters = {'name': 'username','position': 'password'}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'} 
    r = requests.post(url, json=parameters,headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: `json.dumps()` не нужен. К я вам уже написал: [*"Вы вероятно хотели json параметр, а не data использовать"*](https://goo.gl/8JkgVV): `requests.post(url, json=parameters, headers=headers).raise_for_status()`

Comment: Но если status_code для г оказался 200, то когда мы вызываем raise_for_status() мы получаем:None

Comment: как ссылка показывает это комментарий, а не ответ (не содержит решения, комментарий о вопросе -- так как из data словаря в вопросе вы никак parameters словарь в вашем ответе не получите)¶ Задача `.raise_for_status()` выбросить исключение, если запрос неудачный (к примеру, для `r.status_code==400`)